# relocate d3 map to center of screen no matter the device

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I've got [the following d3 map](http://smatthewenglish.com/literate-octo-robot/):

[image]

but as you can see it's all bunched up there in the left corner of the screen- this is sub opimal- ideally I would like it to be centered.

How can I achieve this?

I guess it should be easy but every time I google something like "center align d3 map" I get things about zooming

:/

maybe I need to create a div or something?

the code is [here on my GitHub](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/literate-octo-robot)

also below- it's pretty well commented.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>


<style>
  .border {
    stroke: #000;
    fill: none;

  }
  .graticule {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #777;
    stroke-width: .5px;
    stroke-opacity: .5;
  }

  div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 84px;
    height: 64px;
    padding: 2px;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>



<h1>Administrative Sub-Regions of Europe</h1>

<!-- this is the form at the bottom to change the NUTS -->
<form>
<select id="json_sources" name="json_sources" >
<option value ="nuts0" selected >Source 0</option>
<option value ="nuts1" >Source 1</option>
<option value ="nuts2" >Source 2</option>
<option value ="nuts3" >Source 3</option>
</select>
<form>



<!-- spinner -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/2.0.1/spin.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/colorbrewer.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rveciana/d3-composite-projections/v0.2.0/composite-projections.min.js"></script>


<!-- why do we need this? -->
<section id='chart'>
</section>

<script>

  var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
          .attr("class", "tooltip")
          .style("opacity", 0);

  var width = 600,
      height = 500;

  var projection = d3.geo.conicConformalEurope();
  var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

  var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

  // Find new colours here: http://colorbrewer2.org/
  var scale =  d3.scale
                 .quantize()
                 .domain([10,60])
                 .range(colorbrewer.PuRd[3]);

    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width, "100%")
                .attr("height", height, "100%")
                .call(
                      d3.
                      behavior.
                      zoom().
                      on("zoom", function () {
                                                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" +

                                                     d3.event.translate +

                                                     ")" + " scale(" +

                                                     d3.event.scale +
                                                     ")")
                                              }
                          )
                      )
                .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
                .append("g")


//what the hell does this do?
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(graticule)
            .attr("class", "graticule")
            .attr("d", path);

  // pretty self spoken
  var dropdown = d3.select("#json_sources")

  // config references SPINNER RELATED
  var chartConfig = {
      target : 'chart',
      data_url : './nuts0.json',
      width: 600,
      height: 500,
      val: 90
  };

  // loader settings SPINNER RELATED
  var opts = {
    lines: 9, // The number of lines to draw
    length: 9, // The length of each line
    width: 5, // The line thickness
    radius: 14, // The radius of the inner circle
    color: '#EE3124', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
    speed: 1.9, // Rounds per second
    trail: 40, // Afterglow percentage
    className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
  };

  // SPINNER RELATED
  var target = document.getElementById(chartConfig.target);

// KICK OFF callback function wrapped for loader in 'init' function
function init() {

// trigger loader initial spinner
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);

        // load json data and trigger callback
        d3.json(chartConfig.data_url, function(data) {

            // stop spin.js loader
            spinner.stop();

            // instantiate chart within callback
            chart(data);

        });
}

//call that init function we define above
init();

//here where all the real stuff happens
//in fact all that init stuff is just legacy
//from the spinner example
function chart(data) {



    //start of map making function
    var change = function() {



// trigger loader of the spinner
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);


    // did they change the NUTS?
    var source = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;

    //necessary data processing
    var str1 = source;
    var str2 = ".json";
    var file = str1.concat(str2);
    console.log(file);


      d3.json(file, function(error, europe) {

      d3.csv("povertry_rate.csv", function(error, povrate) {


        //change the map to apadpt to the nuts file
        if (source == "nuts1") {
        var land = topojson.feature(europe, europe.objects.nuts1);
        } else if (source == "nuts2") {
        var land = topojson.feature(europe, europe.objects.nuts2);
        } else if (source == "nuts3") {
        var land = topojson.feature(europe, europe.objects.nuts3);
        } else if (source == "nuts0") {
        var land = topojson.feature(europe, europe.objects.nuts0);
        }


        data = {};
        povrate.forEach(function(d) {
          data[d.GEO] = d['2013'];
        });


        //clear way for the regeneration
        d3.selectAll("path").remove();
        //recreate those map lines
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(graticule)
            .attr("class", "graticule")
            .attr("d", path);

// stop spin.js loader
spinner.stop();

        console.info(data);
        svg
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(land.features)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("d", path)
          .style("stroke","#000")
          .style("stroke-width",".5px")
          .style("fill",function(d){
                var value = data[d.id];
                if (isNaN(value)){
                  value = data[d.id.substring(0,2)];
                }
                if (isNaN(value)){
                  return "#fff";
                }

                return scale(value);
                })
          .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
                var value = data[d.id];
                if (isNaN(value)){
                  value = data[d.id.substring(0,2)];
                }
                div.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", 0.9);
                div.html("<b>"+d.properties.name+"</b><br/>" + value + "%")
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
            })
          .on("mouseout", function(d,i) {
              div.transition()
                  .duration(500)
                  .style("opacity", 0);
            });

            svg
              .append("path")
                .style("fill","none")
                .style("stroke","#000")
                .attr("d", projection.getCompositionBorders());


      });




      })
    }







    dropdown.on("change", change)
    change(); //call that change function once





}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a `d3` question just a little CSS:

```
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: whoa- nice man thank you :D
do you know maybe how I could throw a kind of- bounding box around it- to distiguish it from the background?

Comment: awesome. do you happen to know also how I might center that spinner? or maybe- should I ask it as another SO question?

Comment: @s.matthew.english, the spinner already looks centered to me.